# Lookup unique value which may be duplicated on another tab

Tags: excel, lookup

I have a summary tab with a column of unique identifiers. These identifiers are assigned to other tabs, on which they may duplicated on multiple rows, but only on one of the tabs.

I am trying to input a formula that will find which tab the identifier is on, and then sum a value in that row with any other rows that have the same identifier. I would use a `SUMIF` if there was only 1 instance of the identifier/row, but I am not sure how to work this with duplicate identifier rows.

I'm using `=COUNTA(j2,m2,p2)` to count the instances that I need to capture. Row 2 has the identifier in column B.

On my summary tab, I tried:

```
SUMIF(*range of tabs to search*, B2(*on the summary tab*, *range of COUNTA totals on the non-summary tabs.*)
```

Comment: I think it would help clarify what you are after if you could add some sample data and your desired results. I have a feeling though that `=Sumifs()` or `=Countifs()` would help out here.

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52062241/edit) your post to add what you've tried, some sample data and the expected outcome?

Comment: sounds like you want [3D SUMIF](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-3d-sumif-across-multiple-worksheets)